# installations error : javascript error occurred in the main process

Tags: javascript, wordpress, windows

Good Morning to all.

I have downloaded a software with name **local-by-flywheel-2-1-2-windows.exe** their official website: https://local.getflywheel.com/
This one is the free version for creating WordPress website locally and able to show with clients.

I have tried to install it on window 7 and getting error something bellow 
[image]

any guidance, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a two things you can do to try to get this working:

If it's running on port 80 (or anything less than 1000), check that it's running in admin permissions

Check your Processes list in Task Manager and see if there is a zombie instance running that's still listening on the port. You can also use netstat to see this in cmd.

Comment: thanks for reply can you guide me step by step please I don't understand you? and how to do the process you mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Resolved

Step 1: The problem was that you must be login to your flywheel account on the website or which one side by side opens into your computer.

Step2:  Then run flywheel setup as an administrator.

Thanks